# BCS external content type as lookup

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs

I have written a wcf service to read the title and id column from a list and returning as arraylist. Please find the below code. The webservice is returing the values correctly.Now when i create an external content type and create external list and use this list as lookup in another list. When i select an item from the lookup it is showig data in the binary format. Attached is the screen shot for the same

```
 public Vendor[] GetVendors(string fieldTitle)
        {
            string siteName = "http://myappserver.com/myname/";
            string webName = "Susite2";
            string listName = "Vendors List";
            List<Vendor> listVendor = new List<Vendor>();

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteName))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[webName])
                //using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" + "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>";
                        query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
                        if (items.Count > 0)
                        {

                            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                            {
                                string title = Convert.ToString(item[fieldTitle]);

                                Vendor vendor = new Vendor();
                                vendor.Name = title;
                                vendor.VendorId =item.ID;
                                listVendor.Add(vendor);
                              }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return listVendor.ToArray();

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code worked for me

```
public Vendor[] GetVendors(string strFilter)
        {
            string siteName = "http://myappserver.com/myname/";
            string webName = "Susite2";
            string listName = "Vendors List";
            string fieldTitle = "Title";
            List<Vendor> listVendor = new List<Vendor>();

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteName))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[webName])
                //using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                   SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" + "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>";
                        query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter))
                            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + strFilter + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                        if (items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                            {
                                string title = Convert.ToString(item[fieldTitle]);
                                Vendor vendor = new Vendor();
                                vendor.Name = title;
                                vendor.VendorId = item.ID;
                                listVendor.Add(vendor);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                 return listVendor.OrderBy(a => a.Name).Select(a => a).ToArray();
    }
```